# SSRS 2016 Scale out deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016

Got 2 Servers in Scale out deployment and connection is through a load balancing URL.

1) SSRS01 
2) SSRS02

Everything works fine when the session is running from SSRS02 but keep getting the error from the screenshot below when trying from SSRS01.

I have looked at permissions. They are exactly the same. I can't find anything relevant in the report server logs too.

Any help on this would be really helpful .

[image]

Comment: What do the SSRS log files say?  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: There are no entries relating to this in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by removing the reportserverurl entry in the config file